# why does XmlSlurper throw NumberFormatException?

Tags: grails, groovy

I launch my Grails 2.1.5 app from an IDE with an exception breakpoint set for `NumberFormatException` (meaning that the application will break whenever this exception is thrown).

If I then execute the following code from the Grails console:

```
import  groovy.util.*
import groovyx.net.http.*

def uri = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?artist=Yelle&mbid=f43d43c8-eedf-4628-99b0-04120e7124c8&method=artist.gettopalbums&api_key=6e331f856413a5e3dfc91ec41cea5415&limit=6'

XmlSlurper().parse(uri)
```

The exception breakpoint is triggered because of the following code in `Long.parseLong`

```
public static long parseLong(String s, int radix)
          throws NumberFormatException
{
    if (s == null) {
        throw new NumberFormatException("null");
    }

    // rest of method omitted
}
```

However it seems that `XmlSlurper().parse(uri)` returns the expected value, so I guess this exception is handled somewhere, but I can't figure out where. I'm puzzled about why `Long.parseLong` is called with a null value for the first param. Is this a bug in `XmlSlurper` or just some strange implementation detail?

### Update

As requested, here's the call stack. I'm using JDK 7 and Groovy 1.8.8. I tried debugging it myself, but as you can see, I'm missing a lot of the relevant source files.

```
  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:404)
  at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1571)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source:-1)
  at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source:-1)
  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source:-1)
  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source:-1)
  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source:-1)
  at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source:-1)
  at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source:-1)
  at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:146)
  at groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parse(XmlSlurper.java:212)
```

Comment: Doesn't the ide give you a call stack?

Comment: I put that same code in a groovy console and it works fine. It's not a problem with xmlslurper.

Comment: Probably a strange implementation detail like trying to parse the id attribute of a node as a long without checking to see if it exists first

Comment: @JamesKleeh the exception is handled somewhere, so there's no way to observe this if you just run it in a Groovy console

Comment: @tim_yates I've added the call stack

Comment: Pretty sure Groovy 1.8.8 is bundled with Groovy 1.8.8 ;)

Comment: From that stack trace it's somewhere inside the http URL protocol handler, at a guess it'll be looking for a Content-Length header or something like that. As long as the exception gets caught and handled inside the library you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: [grepcode.com has the class in question](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#HttpURLConnection) if you really want to track this down precisely.

Comment: @IanRoberts the link you provided is from OpenJDK, my stacktrace is using Oracle's JDK

Comment: The Oracle JDK is essentially OpenJDK plus a few closed-source components so it shouldn't make any difference in this case. But my main point was that you shouldn't care - the fact that a certain exception is used internally within a library class is an implementation detail. Users of the library only need to care about exceptions that propagate out of the library back to callers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, [this file from the OpenJDK mercurial repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u-dev/jdk/file/82eb0ebe4ef3/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java) is the version of `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` that is in Java 7 update 25, and the relevant extract is

```
 1570     try {
 1571         cl = Long.parseLong(responses.findValue("content-length"));
 1572     } catch (Exception exc) { };
```

so the `NumberFormatException` will be thrown (and immediately ignored) whenever an HTTP response doesn't have a `Content-Length` header.